# Value of $\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value of $\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor$? Is it $1$ or $0$?

I was told that the answer is $0$ as $\sin{x}$ is less than $x$ as $x\rightarrow0$. Is it correct or are limits exact values?

I know that $\lim_{x\to0}\Bigl\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor$ will be $0$ due to the above mentioned fact.

Comment: $$ \lfloor 1 \rfloor = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Will keep that in mind next time. I thought titles like this make your question appear interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{1}=\cos (0) = 1.$$
Since $\lfloor 1\rfloor=1$ it follows that $\left\lfloor\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right)\right\rfloor=1$.

Comment: So limits are exact values and not values tending to a number, am i right?

Comment: @nicomezi So are limits not exact values?

Comment: If they exist, yes. However, it might be that a limit does not exist (for example $\lim_{x \to \infty} x$ does not exist).

Comment: I missread the question. The answer is correct.

Comment: use \to   instead of -> for tending

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, but using L'Hospital's rule for this limit (as you seem to be doing) is circular. See instead [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Answer (score 4):

Since

- $\lim_{x\to0}(\frac{\sin x}{x})=1 $
- and for $x\ne 0$ sufficiently small: $0<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$

we have that

$$\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0}\Bigl\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=0$$

Comment: Thanks, but the question is answered already.

Comment: @HarshitJoshi Yes I see that, I've only add since the second answer is wrong and my aim was to give a full picture for the difference between the two cases.

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: @HarshitJoshi As you mentioned for any $x\ne 0$ we have $0<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$ and therefore $$\Bigl\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=0 \implies \lim_{x->0}\Bigl\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=0$$

Comment: Still don't understand why is it wrong?

Comment: He is talking about the left and right hand limits.

Comment: @HarshitJoshi Note that $$\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x->0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x->0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=\Bigl\lfloor\,\lim_{x->0^-}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr\rfloor=1$$ in any case the limit is **exactly 1** and therefore the floor of the limit is 1 (but the limit of the floor is 0).

Comment: Yes you are right. Did not look carefully.

Comment: @gimusi I think even the floor of the limit is  0 , because $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}= 0.999999\ldots $, but it is never equal to 1 .We cannot  define the function when denominator is 0.  We define only the $\lim_{x\to 0}$

Answer (score 2):

By the Maclaurin's expansion of $sin(x)$, we have,
$$\sin(x) =\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

As $x\to0$ we compute left hand limit,
$$\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} =\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\left( 1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\cdots\right) $$
$$\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
Further for right hand limit,
$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} =\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left( 1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\cdots\right) $$
$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
Now,
$$\Bigl\lfloor\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lfloor\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\Bigr\rfloor =1  $$